# how to get the size of varchar in the oracle AssociativeArray type

Tags: .net, oracle, associative-array, odp.net, varchar

I have a stored procedure in which I defined a type :

```
type AssocArrayVarchar2_t is table if varchar(10) index by binary_integer;
```

Is there any way to get the size of this varchar type (in this case, it is 10) in the C# code?
(I am using ODP.net and I want to give it to the OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if it is just a locally declared type. Well not without scanning and parsing ALL_SOURCE. You are better off defining the type as `TABLE OF table.column%TYPE` and then you can pick that table/column type from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.

It also ties your variable to the associated database structure